# mplfinance plot with external axis mode, additional plot with date format issue

Tags: python, plot, axis, date-formatting, mplfinance

mplfinance library as far as I know only supports 2 plots, called panel 0 and 1. I would like to have 3 panels, so by that fact, I'm using external axes, to create axes by myself, like this:

```
f = mpf.figure()
(ax1, ax2, ax3) = f.subplots(3, 1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1, 3, 1]}, sharex=True)
f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0, wspace=0)

# mpf.plot requires to create an index column for dates
ohlcv = ohlcv.set_index(column_names[0])

mpf.plot(ohlcv, type='candle', ax=ax2, volume=ax3)
```

It is not possible to add ax1 as a parameter to the `mpf.plot` function (or is it?), so I tried this:

```
ax1.plot(ohlcv.index.values, self._ohlcv['cash'])
```

I assumed it would work because it uses the same index column as `mpf.plot`.

**The result:**

[image: X axis not aligned between axes 1, 2, and 3]

So I don't know how should I plot `ax1` to align with `ax2` and `ax3`.

If I don't use `sharex=True` the plot looks like this:
[image]

It looks fine, but I guess it uses a different date format and it's not perfectly aligned with ax2 and ax3. So how can I make this work?

**Example code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf

ohlcv = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Date': [1609459200, 1609545600, 1609632000, 1609718400, 1609804800, 1609891200, 1609977600, 1610064000],
     'Open': [11.25, 12.61, 11.93, 10.52, 10.41, 11.66, 11.47, 12.14],
     'High': [12.63, 13.2, 11.94, 12.12, 15.02, 11.71, 12.47, 13.01],
     'Low': [11.10, 11.68, 9.93, 10.3, 10.31, 11.26, 10.46, 12.13],
     'Close': [12.61, 11.93, 10.52, 10.41, 11.66, 11.47, 12.14, 12.96],
     'Volume': [108, 102, 105, 116, 164, 145, 132, 117],
     'cash': [100.0, 100.295, 100.295, 100.295, 95.685, 95.635, 95.635, 95.635]
     })

ohlcv.iloc[:, 0] = pd.to_datetime(ohlcv.iloc[:, 0], unit='s')
ohlcv = ohlcv.set_index('Date')

f = mpf.figure()
(ax1, ax2, ax3) = f.subplots(3, 1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1, 3, 1]})   # add sharex=True as a param
f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0, wspace=0)

mpf.plot(ohlcv, type='candle', ax=ax2, volume=ax3)

ax1.plot(ohlcv.index.values, ohlcv['cash'])
ax1.legend(['Cash'], loc='best')

mpf.show()
```

Edit:

Now that I'm taking a closer look, volume bars are also oversized and visually not aligned correctly below the candles. Grid lines are also pretty confusing between axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**mplfinance actually supports up to 32 panels** when using [**the panels method**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/panels.ipynb) of subplots.  (Although the [documentation](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/markdown/subplots.md) says that it is limited to 10 panels, as [you can see here](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md) with **version v0.12.7a17** the maximum number of panels was increased from 10 to 32.  `pip install --upgrade mplfinance` to get the latest version).

**Please read the [above mentioned documentation on the panels method](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/panels.ipynb),** after which, if you still have questions, feel free to post them here or open another SO question.

---

By the way, the [external axis method](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/markdown/subplots.md#external-axes-method), which you appear to be using above, is not needed for what you are trying to accomplish.  Generally, using external axes is discouraged (except when absolutlely needed) because it blocks some mplfinance features (requiring you to code those features yourself if you want them).  Rather, *if you require* [access to the mplfinance Figure and Axes](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/wiki/Acessing-mplfinance-Figure-and-Axes-objects) objects, I would encourage you to *use the* `returnfig=True` *method* which can provide that access while retaining full mplfinance functionality.

I hope this answer helps.  Full disclosure: I am the maintainer of the mplfinance library.

---

As an example, using your code/data from above:

```py
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf
ohlcv = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Date': [1609459200, 1609545600, 1609632000, 1609718400,
              1609804800, 1609891200, 1609977600, 1610064000],
     'Open': [11.25, 12.61, 11.93, 10.52, 10.41, 11.66, 11.47, 12.14],
     'High': [12.63, 13.2, 11.94, 12.12, 15.02, 11.71, 12.47, 13.01],
     'Low': [11.10, 11.68, 9.93, 10.3, 10.31, 11.26, 10.46, 12.13],
     'Close': [12.61, 11.93, 10.52, 10.41, 11.66, 11.47, 12.14, 12.96],
     'Volume': [108, 102, 105, 116, 164, 145, 132, 117],
     'cash': [100.0, 100.295, 100.295, 100.295, 95.685, 95.635, 95.635, 95.635]
     })

ohlcv.iloc[:, 0] = pd.to_datetime(ohlcv.iloc[:, 0], unit='s')
ohlcv = ohlcv.set_index('Date')

ap = mpf.make_addplot(ohlcv['cash'],panel=0,ylabel='Cash')
mpf.plot(ohlcv,
         type='candle',
         volume=True,
         main_panel=1,
         volume_panel=2,
         addplot=ap,
         figsize=(7,7))
```

The result is:

[image]

It is also possible to tweak many features of the plot (widths and colors of candles and volume bars, panel sizes, etc.) as described in [the documentation](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance#contents-and-tutorials).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was confused about some things, but your answer clarified a lot! I will definitely read the documentations to get a more in depth understanding about how to use your library correctly and effectively.